# How can we separate mixed signals

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

A receiver receive multiple signals from multiple sensors, the received signals is shown in the figure below :

[image]

I'm using MATLAB and I don't know how to separate the mixed signals. Are there any techniques or methods used to separate mixed signals ?

Comment: Question need some more info to comment .. Yes , you receive bunch of signals when you simply turn on  the receiver (if there is something going on in the band u are tuning to ). There are protocols like WLAN, LTE, BLE etc which have preamble to detect the start of packet. You have to check the standard on which you are working on

Comment: You need to tell us what the signals are and how they're mixed.  Are they transmitted on separate carrier waves, pcm modulated at separate times, are two sensors shorted together, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Nouali Ibrahim Yassine,

Without any additional information about the two signals, what you are trying to do is a blind source separation. This means that you will have to use a set of advanced statistical tools ( principal components analysis or independent component analysis for example, I would go more for the Independant component analysis) to try to figure out different signal patterns.

If you can have additional information about your signals (I guess you know your sensors, their number, their signal characteristics such as spectral distribution or some pre recorded patterns that you can use to correlate with the mixed signal, their inter-correlation) You may find a simpler solution to your problem.

In any case, here is some lecture about the methods that I stated. There may be other ones that are better suited for your problem.

Blind source seperation in general : 
https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/laurent.albera/alberasiteweb/bss.html
Principal component analysis : 
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/
Principal component analysis versus Independant component analysis : 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-PCA-and-ICA

Best regards,

Mourad